# Filter out sequences of records in R/Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I have a table of sequential records of different individuals that look something like this:

(Setting this up in R, although Python solutions are also OK.)

```
set.seed(22)

df <- data.frame(
  score = c(1, 4, 15, 12, 6,  7, 12, 7, 8, 5,  12, 19, 1, 4, 7, 12, 3, 5, 9, 4),
  info = sample(1:100, 20)
)
```

| score | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 88 |
| 15 | 74 |
| 12 | 94 |
| 6 | 44 |
| 7 | 59 |
| 12 | 81 |
| 7 | 67 |
| 8 | 48 |
| 5 | 16 |
| 12 | 58 |
| 19 | 72 |
| 1 | 62 |
| 4 | 31 |
| 7 | 65 |
| 12 | 49 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 5 | 68 |
| 9 | 33 |
| 4 | 32 |

The goal is to filter out certain rows of the table based on the score sequence. Here are the rules in human logic. Take the scores as a list:

1, 4, 15, 12, 6, 7, 12, 7, 8, 5 12, 19, 1, 4, 7 12, 3, 5, 9, 4

Step 1: Divide the list into sub-lists by instances of score == 12.

(The last sub-list is included regardless if it ends with the score == 12. And if the list do not contain any instances of score == 12, there would be one sub-list, i.e.: the entire list.)

[1, 4, 15, 12], [6, 7, 12], [7, 8, 5, 12], [19, 1, 4, 7, 12], [3, 5, 9, 4]

Step 2: Filter out all sub-lists that do not contain one or more instances of scores == 4.

[1, 4, 15, 12], [19, 1, 4, 7, 12], [3, 5, 9, 4]

Step 3: Then filter the data frame to include the rows corresponding to these scores only.

| score | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 88 |
| 15 | 74 |
| 12 | 94 |
| 19 | 72 |
| 1 | 62 |
| 4 | 31 |
| 7 | 65 |
| 12 | 49 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 5 | 68 |
| 9 | 33 |
| 4 | 32 |

Note that the scores are *neither* unique nor ordinal.

What would be the best way to implement this routine in either R or Python, hopefully without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method.

1. First create a `vec` vector containing the index position where `df$score == 12`. Also include 0 and `now(df)` to it, which will be used later in `lapply`
2. Create sublists `mylist` that ends with `score == 12`. `deframe` is used to create a named vector from a two-column dataframe using `lapply`
3. Use the `%in%` operator to see if 4 is contained in the sublist, remove ones that don't contain 4
4. And use `enframe` to create a two-column dataframe from a named vector.

```
vec <- sort(c(0, which(df$score == 12), nrow(df)))
mylist <- lapply(1:(length(vec) - 1), function(x) deframe(df[2:1])[(vec[x]+1):vec[x+1]])
enframe(mylist[sapply(mylist, function(x) 4 %in% x)] %>% unlist(), value = "score", name = "info")[2:1]

# A tibble: 13 × 2
   score info 
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 9    
 2     4 88   
 3    15 74   
 4    12 94   
 5    19 72   
 6     1 62   
 7     4 31   
 8     7 65   
 9    12 49   
10     3 21   
11     5 68   
12     9 33   
13     4 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`, we can use `cumsum` on a logical vector (`score == 12`) to create a grouping column and then `filter` if there is a 4 `%in%` score to keep only those groups and finally remove the `grp` column created - `dplyr` is used for the piping and the `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = lag(cumsum(score == 12), default = 0)) %>% 
   filter(4 %in% score) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 × 2
   score  info
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1     9
 2     4    88
 3    15    74
 4    12    94
 5    19    72
 6     1    62
 7     4    31
 8     7    65
 9    12    49
10     3    21
11     5    68
12     9    33
13     4    32
```